# App Analytics for device where network connectivity varies

Tags: ios, google-analytics, react-native

Attempting to set up analytics for a react native app, and was going to use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-analytics.

An issue though, is that there are times where the device may lose network connectivity. Are there any good libraries/solutions for storing events/views app side, then batch uploading them to something like google analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the actual iOS & Android SDK for Google Analytics, via the following react native bridge - https://github.com/idehub/react-native-google-analytics-bridge

As per [docs for iOS](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/dispatch) & [android](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/dispatch)

> If a user loses network access or quits your app while there are still
>   hits waiting to be dispatched, those hits are persisted in local
>   storage. They will be dispatched the next time your app is running and
>   dispatch is called.

Comment: Wow -- can't believe I missed that one in all of my googling. Have you used this before? Any word on accuracy? Have coworkers that worry events tracking isn't 100% accurate.

Comment: @R.Jacobs: No, I have not used it. I hope it works for you.